# GOOGLEFINANCE in Google Sheets to get high & low and timestamp of high/low

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, google-finance

I'm using Google Finance calls in Google Sheets for some calculations.

I've got 2 formulas, one to find the low price, and one to find the high price from a certain date:

```
=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA","low",7/23/2018,TODAY(),1),,2))

=MAX(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA","high",7/23/2018,TODAY(),1),,2))
```

These work as I expect to show just the low/high price, but now I'd like to also have the associated timestamp in another column next to it.

So it would roughly look like this:

```
|Ticker | Low    | Low Date | High   | High Date |

| TSLA  | 176.99 | 6/3/2019 | 387.46 | 8/7/2018  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"TSLA", MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "low",  "7/23/2018", TODAY(), 1),, 2)),
  VLOOKUP(MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "low",  "7/23/2018", TODAY(), 1),, 2)), 
             {INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "low",  "7/23/2018", TODAY(), 1),, 2), 
                    GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "low",  "7/23/2018", TODAY(), 1)}, 2, 0), 
          MAX(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "high", "7/23/2018", TODAY(), 1),, 2)),
  VLOOKUP(MAX(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "high", "7/23/2018", TODAY(), 1),, 2)), 
             {INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "high", "7/23/2018", TODAY(), 1),, 2), 
                    GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "high", "7/23/2018", TODAY(), 1)}, 2, 0)}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks!  That works well -- I made a mistake in my initial post.  In that the "low" part of the formula should be MIN( ) not MAX( ).  Would you mind fixing in your answer and then I will accept?

Comment: @mainstringargs sure, done